# How to visualize HeteroData pytorch geometric graph with any tool?

Tags: networkx, visualization, graph-visualization, pytorch-geometric

Hello what is a good way to visualize a pyg HeteroData object ?
(defined similarly: https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/heterogeneous.html#creating-heterogeneous-gnns )

I tried with networkx but I think it is restricted to homogeneous graph ( it is possible to convert it but it is much less informative).

```
g = torch_geometric.utils.to_networkx(data.to_homogeneous(), to_undirected=False )
```

Did anyone try to do it with other python lib (matplotlib) or js (sigma.js/d3.js)?

Any docs link you can share?

Comment: Eventually I used sigma.js after exporting the graph but it's quite lengthy solution and kinda hacky - so the question remains open.

Answer (score -1):

I have done the following:

```py
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from torch_geometric.nn import to_hetero

g = torch_geometric.utils.to_networkx(data.to_homogeneous())
# Networkx seems to create extra nodes from our heterogeneous graph, so I remove them
isolated_nodes = [node for node in g.nodes() if g.out_degree(node) == 0]
[g.remove_node(i_n) for i_n in isolated_nodes]
# Plot the graph
nx.draw(g, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, it's true that it was "flattened" to a homogeneous, while it'd be more interesting to, for example, use different colors for different types of nodes.

Comment: This is a homogeneous visualization i.e. no visual distinction but thanks it may be useful for someone else

Comment: That's what I emphasized in my answer "However, it's true that it was "flattened" to a homogeneous, while it'd be more interesting to, for example, use different colors for different types of nodes."

Comment: Hello yes but the question is about heteroData.